# how to join multiple results from 2 tables in laravel and return them

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

i have 3 tables (users, main menus, sub menus).
each of these tables contain role_id column.
in menus tables (main & sub) i have items to show for all users (no matter what user_role is), and items to show for specific users (some for admins, some for regular users).
now, when an admin logged in, i want gather a result of menus that contains public menus and also menus specified for admin role.
and when a user logged in, i want gather a result of menus that contain public menus and also menus specified for regular users.
NOTE: menus and subs that are for all users does not have role_id (`role_id=NULL`)
menus and subs for admins have `role_id=1`
menus and subs for regular users have `role_id=8`

i write following code but this only gives menus that have specific role_id, i want to join menus and subs that have `role_id=NULL` to the result.

```
public function MenuPicker(User $user)
{
    //get role of logged in user
   $role = $user->role()->first();

   //get menus of user related to role
    return $role->main_menus()->with('sub_menus')->get();

}
```

this is main menu class:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function sub_menus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserSubMenu::class);
}
```

and this is sub menu class:

```
public function main_menu()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserMainMenu::class);
}
```

looking forward to hearing from you.
thanks.

Comment: main_menu table should have submenu id not role id

Comment: @KamleshPaul it has submenu id already. but what if some of these submenus shouldn't show to regular users??